# xcodebuild commands give different results when run from the command line than when run from within Jenkins

Tags: xcode, jenkins, xcodebuild

I'm setting up a CI system using Jenkins and was finding that the build was failing because xcodebuild reports there are no schemes when I was executing the line

-xcodebuild -workspace XXX -scheme NNN.

I couldn't figure out why this could be happening, so to eliminate something screwy being up with my workspace I created a new project template using XCode and found that I am getting a difference in behavior for any xcodebuild command and for any workspace/project.

The template project was called scrap and if from the terminal command line I run this command for example:

```
  xcodebuild -list
```

It outputs

```
Information about project "scrap":
    Targets:
        scrap

    Build Configurations:
        Debug
        Release

    If no build configuration is specified and -scheme is not passed then "Release" is used.

    Schemes:
        scrap
```

But if I run xcodebuild -list from within Jenkins then the output instead is:

```
Building in workspace /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/scrap
[scrap] $ /bin/sh -xe /var/folders/ph/s6dvlfq9769741g_yzmjlmz000007c/T/hudson3765407964219991487.sh
+ xcodebuild -list
Information about project "scrap":
    Targets:
        scrap

    Build Configurations:
        Debug
        Release

    If no build configuration is specified and -scheme is not passed then "Release" is used.

    This project contains no schemes.
```

This is the most simple of jenkins jobs - all I do is create a new job, set it to a free-style software project, then add a build step of Execut shell and add the  xcodebuild -list command, that's it.

Why is xcodebuild saying there are no schemes when there are? And why is it behaving differently when run from within Jenkins?

Comment: Have you tried passing the name without extension?

Comment: I've revised my question as I found its a much more generic problem, simply doing "xcodebuild -list" for example gives different results from the command line as from within Jenkins.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Figured out that all you need to do is to set the scheme to be shared.
Scheme > Manage Schemes
Make sure "Shared" is checked.

This will then generate out a new folder/file .../xcshareddata/xcschemes/???.xcscheme

Check this file into your source control and scheme should now appear on your jenkins box.

Comment: Where is this Scheme > Manage Schemes?

Comment: On XCode 5, click on Target (on the right of the "stop" button), then you should see "Manage Schemes"

Answer (score 0):

you must ignore your *.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/*.xcuserdatad in your .gitignore file.
xcodebuild -list get schemes from *.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/*.xcuserdatad/xcschemes.
jenkins server has no this file so get no schemes,you can open *.xcodeproj in your jenkins server,it will create the file and then do xcodebuild -list can get the current schemes.I have the same problem and solved by the method above.